# Generic function for Map of maps in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to write a generic function which will accept both of the following data types

```
Map <Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>
Map <Integer, Map<Integer, Double>>
```

My function looks like this,

```
function(Map<Integer, Map<Integer, ? extends Number>> arg) {}
```

But I am getting an incompatible type error. It works for a Map, but not for map of Maps. I am not able to understand why? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's reduce the problem by using `Set`s instead:

```
Set<Set<Long>> longSetSet = null;
Set<Set<Double>> doubleSetSet = null;

Set<Set<? extends Number>> someNumberSetSet;

// try assigning them
someNumberSetSet = longSetSet;   //
someNumberSetSet = doubleSetSet; // compiler errors - incompatible types
```

At first glance you might wonder why this assignment is illegal, since after all you can assign a `Set<Long>` to `Set<? extends Number>` The reason is that [generics are not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/697449). The compiler prevents you from assigning a `Set<Set<Long>>` to `Set<Set<? extends Number>>` for the same reason it won't let you assign a `Set<Long>` to a `Set<Number>`. See the linked answer for more details.

As a workaround, you can use a type parameter in your method signature as other answers have suggested. You can also use another wildcard to make the assignment legal:

```
Set<? extends Set<? extends Number>> someNumberSetSet;

someNumberSetSet = longSetSet;   //
someNumberSetSet = doubleSetSet; // legal now
```

Or in your example:

```
function(Map<Integer, ? extends Map<Integer, ? extends Number>> arg) { }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like

```
static <T extends Number> void function(Map<Integer, Map<Integer, T>> map) {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>();
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>>();
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> map3 = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, String>>();
    function(map1);
    function(map2);
    function(map3);// <-- compilation error here, String is not Number
}
```

Comment: Sweet. It works. Is there any place where I can read why my function did not work? :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just parameterize the method?

```
public <T extends Number> void function(Map<Integer, Map<Integer, T>>) { ... }
```

I've found that the wildcard capture tends to confuse people as to what it really does.

`Map<Integer, ? extends Number>` really means any `Map` whose key is `Integer` and whose value is a type derived from `Number`.  This means `Map<Integer, Integer>,` `Map<Integer,Long>`.

For this reason, you can never really add to those collections, because of the wildcard the compiler can't tell what the real type is in order to add.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void test(Map<Integer, Map<Integer, ? extends Number>> a) { }
```

This actually works just fine for me (JavaSE-1.6).